# Clean code for array comparison

Tags: c#

Following snippet reads CSV Line count using BinaryReader.

Currently it checks `\r` and `\n` for line delimiters.

```
        private static int GetLineCount(string fileName)
        {
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(fileName));
            int lineCount = 0;

            char lastChar = reader.ReadChar();
            char newChar = new char();

            do
            {
                newChar = reader.ReadChar();
                if (lastChar == '\r' && newChar == '\n')
                {
                    lineCount++;
                }
                lastChar = newChar;
            } while (reader.PeekChar() != -1);
            return lineCount;
        }
```

I want to use `Environment.NewLine` string and make it work on `windows\unix`.

I want to refactor above to find word occurance and then match for the word `Environment.NewLine`. The issue is that I am not able to refactor following for word (more specifically change `lastChar` , `newChar` into Array.

```
                do
                {
                    newChar = reader.ReadChar();
                    if (lastChar == '\r' && newChar == '\n')
                    {
                        lineCount++;
                    }
                    lastChar = newChar;
                } while (reader.PeekChar() != -1);
```

Comment: Both `BinaryReader` and `File.OpenRead()` are `IDisposable` resources - wrap them in a `using` statement for deterministic disposal.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to do line count or an array comparison (as the title suggests)? Also, do you need an exact count in the case of a large file? If you know the total file size and you know the length of the first 20,000 lines, then you could have a good guess of what the line count is approximately. What are you trying to do at the higher level?

Comment: Array-comparison (or specifically word comparison) comes into picture  as I want to use `Environment.NewLine`. At higher level I am finding exact line count for big files ( >1GB) for progress reporting. Currently It is done using Stream Current Read position divided by file length. But that is not acceptable (as inconsistent due to other file types involved), in our overall context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Environment.NewLine` always returns `\r\n` so it won't help you in parsing different line endings.

If your task is to count the number of lines then it would be much easier just to do smth. like:

```
    private static int GetLineCount(string fileName)
    {
        return File.ReadLines(fileName).Count();
    }
```

`ReadLines` method automatically parses different line endings.

Comment: 1. Environment.NewLine returns line feed. On unix it is LF (\n), on Mac it is CR(\r), on windows it is CRLF(\r\n). 2. Try running the code on large files (> 2 GB), It will throw OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: @Tilak: Why would you line count a 2gb file?...

Comment: 2GB is for illustration, Files are large in size (100MB - 1GB), but to answer your question, I need to show message like `Processing x row in Total N rows`.

Comment: @Tilak, I've used `ReadLines` method that returns a stream of lines. You probably confused it with `ReadAllLines` which indeed loads all lines in memory. The only case when this code would throw `OutOfMemoryException` is when your file would have a  line longer than 2GBs which is very-very unlikely for text files

Comment: @Tilak about `Environment.NewLine` - are you talking about running this .NET code on Mac/Unix? Or parsing files coming from those platforms? [.NET framework explicitly specifies](http://typedescriptor.net/browse/members/828101-System.Environment.NewLine) `\r\n` as a value for `Environment.NewLine`, not sure about Mono.

Comment: @You are right that I got confused with `ReadAllLines`. I need to check this out, but as it is returning `IEnumerable` i suspect it loads all the data into memory (may be not that i need to check)

Comment: I can guarantee that `ReadLines` reads the file lazily

Comment: Thanks. It is good to know. (I was aware that something of this sort exist for reading file lines/enumerating files/directories) but never looked at the API. But still I was expecting refactoring of my code. `File.ReadLines` functionality (corresponding to my requirements) can be achieved with `StreamReader.ReadLine` in a loop. There is a trade-off (how much, i need to benchmark) to convert line into string which is not needed for line count.

Comment: `File.ReadLines` does exactly that, reads the lines using `StreamReader.ReadLine` and returns them as lazy `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: On Mono on Unix `Environment.Newline` indeed returns just `"\n"`.

Comment: In any case when your task is to calculate line count it's more important where the file came from rather than current OS